# Promise condition equal

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I want to wait in my code until two values are the same. For this I use

```
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if(curCount == maxTests) resolve;
    });
```

But I think, this is only called one time. How I can make it that if both values are the same the promise is resolved? How to avoid that it will never send a resolve?

UPDATE:
Some requested the function that makes trouble. Here is the whole function, without it sub function. The function will fill the q-queue to fullfill the tests sync.  The problem ist that `req.body.selection.forEach` immediately returns but I want to wait until the whole queue is ready. So my idea was to add a promise to the end and hit until current and max are the same.

```
router.post('/imgtest', async (req, res) => {

    console.log('Start Image Test');

    //Er kommt an.
    req.setTimeout(5000000); // Nach Adam Riese 83 Minuten.
    process.setMaxListeners(0);

    io = req.app.get('socketio');

    //Caluclate the max amounnt of tests
    const maxTests = req.body.selection.length * req.body.servers.length;
    var curCount = 0;


    //RETURN IF THIS IS READY. CURRENTLY IT RETURNS IMMEDIATLY
    req.body.selection.forEach(async function(entry) {

        //Jetzt erstmal die Domain aus der DB holen
        var dbUrl = await getUrl(entry);
        console.log('tapsi');

        var bildFormat = '';

        var arrQuestionmark = dbUrl.split('?');
        if(arrQuestionmark.length==2){
            if(arrQuestionmark[1].includes('&')){
                var arrAnd = arrQuestionmark[1].split('&');
                arrAnd.forEach(function(entry) {
                    if(entry.includes('format=')){
                        var arrFormat = entry.split('=');
                        bildFormat = arrFormat[1];

                    }
                });
            }
        }

        var masterName = uuidv1();
        const orgpath = path.resolve(__basedir, 'tests/downloads', masterName + '-.' + bildFormat);

        //Download the MAsterimage
        (async () => {

            await queue.add(() =>downloadImage(dbUrl, 'c11', req.body.domain,  bildFormat, orgpath) );

        })();

        req.body.servers.forEach(async function(xserver) {

            var fileName = masterName + '-' + xserver + '.' + bildFormat;

            const dpath = path.resolve(__basedir, 'tests/downloads', fileName);

            (async () => {
                await queue.add(() => downloadImage(dbUrl, xserver, req.body.domain, bildFormat, dpath));
                //console.log('Done ' + entry);
            })();

            (async () => {
                await queue.add(async() => startCompare(orgpath, dpath, 'null:').then(function(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    curCount++;
                    messageIO(curCount,maxTests);
                }));
                //console.log('done compare ' + entry);
                //fs.unlinkSync(dpath);
            })();



        });


    });


    console.log('Need to wait');

    res.sendStatus(200);

});
```

Comment: Seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you share more details about the problem you're trying to solve? Right now this code doesn't really tell us what the exact issue is.

Comment: What you have will not wait until the values are equal. You are correct that it will only run once. Can you please share a little more about what you're trying to accomplish, and maybe some more code?

Comment: Can you please post the code that shows how you modify curCount and maxTests?

Comment: I have added the requested information. Hope this explains my problem better.

Comment: You should read some good book or tutorials that explain what `await`/`async` does. A code like `(async () => { await queue.add ( … ); })();` does not make any sense. You call an anonymous `async` function without waiting for it to be finished. And in it, you have an `await` that does not really have any effect in your code. It would be equal to just writing `queue.add ( … );`. And `req.body.selection.forEach(async function(entry) {` is also something that does not make any sense. Use either a `for … of` loop, or a `.map(async function(entry) {`  with `Promise.all`.

Comment: I use the module p-queue and I work against its documentation. Book promise resolved ;-) My problem is not all what is inside the forEach loop. This works like a charme. All test are done sync.  My problem is that the foreach do not wait and so I wanted to add to the end a promise that waits until count and max are the same.

Comment: `my problem is not all what is inside the forEach loop. This works like a charme.`  it is still an incorrect usage of Promises and `await`/`async`. It might seem to work, but it is wrong and might - and most certainly will - result in unexpected behavior at some time in the future or in another scenario.

Comment: What they show on [p-queue: Advanced example](https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-queue#advanced-example) is really some bad coding style and not a good source of learning how to use Promises and `await`/`async` it is, in fact, quite the opposite. If you know how Promises work, then it is somehow clear what they want to show with that code, but it is still not how you should code.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct in assuming that will only be called once. A way around that is to, within the function, create a loop via `setInterval` - doing a regular check and resolving if true and clearing the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure what trying to achieve but one thing is for certain, `Array.prototype.forEach()` will not `await` even if its callback is async and performing a test inside a `new Promise(...)` constructor won't help.

Good news though, `for` loops will `await`.

Here's the code with `for` loops instead of `.forEach()` (twice), unnecessary stuff removed, and otherwise tidied up.

First a suggestion ...

```
// https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html
// The querystring module provides utilities for parsing and formatting URL query strings.
const querystring = require('querystring');
```

... then:

```
router.post('/imgtest', async (req, res) => {
    req.setTimeout(5000000); // Nach Adam Riese 83 Minuten.
    process.setMaxListeners(0);
    // io = req.app.get('socketio'); // not used
    const masterName = uuidv1(); // moved from inner loop
    for (i=0; i<req.body.selection.length; i++) {
        let entry = req.body.selection[i];
        let dbUrl = await getUrl(entry);
        let bildFormat = querystring.parse(dbUrl).format;
        let orgpath = path.resolve(__basedir, 'tests/downloads', `${masterName}-.${bildFormat}`);
        await queue.add(() => downloadImage(dbUrl, 'c11', req.body.domain, bildFormat, orgpath));
        for (j=0; j<req.body.servers.length; j++) {
            let xserver = req.body.servers[j];
            let dpath = path.resolve(__basedir, 'tests/downloads', `${masterName}-${xserver}.${bildFormat}`);
            await queue.add(() => downloadImage(dbUrl, xserver, req.body.domain, bildFormat, dpath));
            await queue.add(async() => startCompare(orgpath, dpath, 'null:'); // probably safe to remove `async`
            // fs.unlinkSync(dpath); // ???
        }
    }
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

This should get you started. I expect that you still have some way to go. At the very least you need to add a try/catch structure and be prepared to send error/status back to the client.